# lifetime of local variables in c++ coroutine

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

For c++20 coroutine, I am trying to understand whether a local variable in the coroutine needs to be allocated in the heap. I have the a [runnable code in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/84qoT8v4c), which runs with expected output. Part of the code is listed below for our discussion.

```
generator<int> my_coroutine()
{

  // Does vec needs to allocated in heap?
  // auto vec = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(std::initializer_list<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
  auto vec = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  for (auto&& i : vec)
  {
    co_yield i;
  }
}

int main()
{
  for (auto i : my_coroutine())
  {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

## My questions

1. Is the vec's lifetime spans the current suspension point. What does the "spans the current suspension point" really mean
2. Should I allocate vec in heap using `std::make_shared`?
3. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), I see the following in the **Execution** section. Does it mean that the coroutine state will make a copy of `vec` in the heap? (no matter whether `vec` is `vector<int>` or `shared_ptr<vector<int>>`)

> the coroutine state, which is an internal, heap-allocated (unless the allocation is optimized out), object that contains
>
> 1. the promise object
> 2. the parameters (all copied by value)
> 3. some representation of the current suspension point, so that a resume knows where to continue, and a destroy knows what local variables were in scope
> 4. local variables and temporaries whose lifetime spans the current suspension point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of await-style coroutines (in pretty much every language that offers them) is that the code looks like synchronous code while having the ability to execute, to some degree, asynchronously. The `await`-equivalent expressions don't fundamentally alter the nature of the code around them, and you can reason about the code as though everything happens in-order. For C++ coroutines, this includes automatic variables.

If you make a local `vector<int>`, that variable works the same way regardless of whether its a coroutine. If you have this declaration: `vector<int> vec = ...;`, you can use the name `vec` to refer to that object at any pointer after its declaration, but before leaving the scope the declaration was placed within.

This is true whether there is a `co_await` between those points or not. That's what "lifetime spans the current suspension point" means: accessing a variable whose lifetime began before some suspension point at a place after that suspension point.

Put simply, if you access a locally-declared object across suspension points, that object needs to be preserved somewhere, so that it still exists after the suspension and resumption of the coroutine. The wiki is explaining how that works.

Comment: can you also elaborate what this means from cpp refrerence: `the coroutine state contains local variables and temporaries whose lifetime spans the current suspension point.` So there is another copy of `vec` that is in the coroutine state and in heap?

Comment: @doraemon: I don't know what there is to elaborate on. `vec` is `vec`. It's one object. It lives in a place that will survive suspension. Or more specifically, it lives wherever the rest of the coroutine state lives. The code has the same meaning without the `co_await`s as it does with them.

Comment: @doraemon The coroutine state is where all of the coroutine's data is stored.  The compiler will decide where to put it such that it will survive for the lifetime of the coroutine.  Whether that's the stack or the heap or somewhere else is up to the compiler.  The C++ standard doesn't specify anything about any stack or heap anywhere.  It only specifies the lifetime of objects.  It's up to the compiler to decide where to put the objects and how to allocate storage for them as long as it fulfils the lifetime requirements set out by the compiler.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Is the "coroutine" and the "coroutine state" the same thing? I thought they are different things, coroutine's local variables are in stack and the coroutine state contains more stuff and is in stack. Is this understanding completely wrong?

Comment: @doraemon: What do you mean by "in stack"? The variables work like *variables*; their lifetimes are scoped based on the structure of the C++ code and where execution proceeds to. That's standard C++ stuff. Don't try to out-think the language; this is all much simpler than you're making it.

Comment: Now I gradually realize my understanding was wrong, although my understanding is still not complete. My previous thought was that the caller `main` calls a function `my_coroutine` which returns a `promise.get_return_object()` to the caller. Calling this function results in a new frame in the stack. I thought this function `my_coroutine` is the so called "coroutine", which owns the local variables such as `vec`. This is what I thought as "`vec` in the stack". Along with this, there are other states being kept in the heap, which is the so called "coroutine state". The above seems to be wrong.